# Problem with Amd drivers 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I'm having a problem with my Amd R5 M330 (I have a notebook with also a i5-5200U that has an integrated graphics card).

Searching on the Internet, I found that I can run applications with my discrete card launching them with `DRI_PRIME=1 <application>`.
The problem is that it generates black windows, for example when I run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears`. The frame rate is at about 10k fps but the window is black, whereas if I run it without "DRI_PRIME", the frame rate is lower but I can see the content of the window.

It happens with all the programs I execute with my discrete card.
Can you help me?